# how to extract value of key by id in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, object

I am beginner coder. I sent obj to php like this

> [{"id":"1","word":"book","pos":"ND","domain":"Book1","property":"label","range":"book","type":"Class"},{"id":"2","word":"book","pos":"DD","domain":"Reference_Book","property":"label","range":"reference book","type":"Class"},{"id":"3","word":"book","pos":"NN","domain":"book_17","property":"hasTitle","range":"The HundredPage Machine Learning Book","type":"Book"},{"id":"4","word":"author","pos":"NN","domain":"book_17","property":"hasTitle","range":"The HundredPage Machine Learning Book","type":"Book"},{"id":"5","word":"author","pos":"NN","domain":"book_17","property":"hasTitle","range":"The HundredPage Machine Learning Book","type":"Book"},{"id":"6","word":"author","pos":"NN","domain":"book_17","property":"hasTitle","range":"The HundredPage Machine Learning Book","type":"Book"},{"id":"7","word":"c","pos":"CC","domain":"book_17","property":"hasTitle","range":"The HundredPage Machine Learning Book","type":"Book"},{"id":"8","word":"c","pos":"AA","domain":"book_17","property":"hasTitle","range":"The HundredPage Machine Learning Book","type":"Book"},{"id":"9","word":"lock","pos":"GG","domain":"book_17","property":"hasTitle","range":"The HundredPage Machine Learning Book","type":"Book"},{"id":"10","word":"lock","pos":"NN","domain":"book_17","property":"hasTitle","range":"The HundredPage Machine Learning Book","type":"Book"}]

and then I want to extract this array by id in php side. I got value when I extract this in jquery like this

```
var myObj = {};

$.each(arr, function(i,val)
{
    //var word_arr = []
    var arr = [];
    myObj[val.id] = val.word;
}) 
console.log(myObj)
```

The attacted picture is result when i extracted above obj

[image: code snippet]

Comment: How are you sending the object to PHP? If you're sending it as JSON, use `json_decode()` to convert it to a PHP object or associative array. If you're sending it as the `data:` option in `$.ajax`, the object keys are keys in `$_POST`.

Comment: Thank you.. Sir, it was sent as JSON, and used json_decode() to convert it .. Now it is ok for me.. Thank agaian..

Answer (score 0):

when we want to access array, we use **myObj[index]**

and when we want to access object, we use **myObj->item**

example for object use in php:

```
<?php
foreach($myObj as $Ob){
    echo $Ob -> id;
    echo $Ob -> word;
    //and so on
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.. It is nice for me.

Comment: My Pleasure, Sir